# Https error when titanium sdk is updated from 5.1.2 to 6.0.3

Tags: appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-titanium

I updated Titanium SDK of my app from 5.1.2 to 6.0.3. After this Https connection to my sitemender server is not working. Same code was working in 5.1.2. This is the error coming
"The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “xxxxxxxx” which could put your confidential information at risk."

Thanks.

Comment: have you validated the certificate on your website?

Comment: It was working good till i updated the Titanium SDK. Can you help me in understanding validating the certificate what you mean by. Thank you

Comment: Something might've changed for the better to validate certificates. So... have you validated your certificate? It sounds like you use a non valid one

Comment: Hello, This guide should help http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.UI.WebView-event-sslerror also the issue reported in https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-4488. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The endpoint's certificate is expired or invalid, so you need to fix that. If you can't, or you just want Titanium (I'm guessing with iOS) to behave the same was as with the older SDK and ignore the invalid certificate, then set [validatesSecureCertificate](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-property-validatesSecureCertificate) to `false`.

```
var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient({
    validatesSecureCertificate: false
});
```